# SQL Server - Grouping to one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have problem with the columns right now. The result I expect suppose to be like this:

```
EmployeeID    EducationalLoan
--------------
1             0.00
2             100.00
```

But the result shows,

```
EmployeeID    EducationalLoan
--------------
1             100.00
2             100.00
```

What I am trying to achieved this time is that I want to see only the employee loan deduction price on the other hand it only shows 0.00.

I know theres a little trick behind, Can someone help me with it?

```
    DECLARE @EmployeeID AS INTEGER

SET @EmployeeID = 0;
SELECT DISTINCT
        [EmployeeID] = emp.EmployeeID,
        [EducationalLoan] = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM((CAST((lc.LoanAmount / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12)  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0) FROM LoanContract lc WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = 1)
FROM Employee emp
    INNER JOIN Salary sal ON sal.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN LoanContract lc ON lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
    LEFT JOIN LoanPayments lp ON lp.LoanID = lc.LoanID
    LEFT JOIN LoanFrequency lf ON lf.LoanFrequencyID = lc.LoanFrequencyID
WHERE emp.EmployeeID IN (SELECT EmployeeID FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID LIKE '%' + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@EmployeeID,0) <> 0 THEN CAST(ISNULL(@EmployeeID, 0) AS VARCHAR(15)) ELSE '' END + '%')
GROUP BY emp.EmployeeID, lt.LoanTypeID
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL + DML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not filter by employee in your subquery

```
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM((CAST((lc.LoanAmount / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12)  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0) 
    FROM LoanContract lc 
    WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = 1
```

should be something like this:

```
    SELECT ...
    FROM LoanContract lc 
    WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = 1 
    AND lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
```

Comment: @Voltech, You saved my day! Thank you so much!